# Windows Batch File - Move files with same file name but different extension

Tags: batch-file

I have written an small batch file that moves all content from one folder to another. 
This works fine. However, the source folder contains two types of files. One of the types is .doc and the other is .xml. Both files have the same name. But sometimes, one of the files (either .doc or .xml) is missing.

```
@echo off
move /y "\\networklocation\folder\folder\*.*" "M:\localfolder"
```

The question is how to make my script move only couples of .doc and .xml files that have the same name. For example, the source contains 1.doc, 2.doc and 1.xml. The script should only move 1.doc and 1.xml. 2.doc should stay in the source folder.

I've looked for this particular problem but have not found really anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for %%i in ("\\networklocation\folder\folder\*.doc") do (
    if exist "%%~dpni.xml" (
        move /y "%%~i" "M:\localfolder"
        move /y "%%~dpni.xml" "M:\localfolder"
    )
)
```

Comment: Your script worked just fine. I did forget that I use longer extensions then just .xml. The complete extensions are .doc.metadata.properties.xml. After adjusting this into your code it worked properly. Thx

Comment: Yes, in cmd the extension starts with the last dot, if any.

Comment: Just one more question. Why do u use i with the docs, and dpni for the xmls? I know that i is just a counter. But what does dpni stand for, and if it stands for nothing, why not just use i here too?

Comment: Found an answer to that on <http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true>